# Cannot setstate with data returned from chased promises in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I use React and promises and I have a 2 functions. The first one returns me data. That data I use when I call my second function - in which I am making a get request (calling a function where I am making the actual get request). I try to store the response from the 2nd function calling set state, however, it's always undefined or I'm getting the error:

> cannot set state of undefined.

In my code-when I log 'test', its also undefined so somehow the value is not stored / or perhaps not returned anywhere, but I'm not sure how to do it.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  handleInput() {
    multipleAirports(this.state.input.origin.value).then(response => {
        var result = [];
        var test = [];
        var input = this.state.input;
        for (var i = 0; i < response.Airports.length; i++) {
            result.push(anyDestinationData(response.Airports[i].code, input.departuredate, input.returndate, input.maxfare))

           return Promise.all(result).then(function (results) {
                var data = [];
                results.forEach(function (item) {
                    data.push({
                        [item.data.OriginLocation]: item.data.FareInfo
                    })

                });
                test = data;
            })
        }
        this.setState({
            flightData: test
        })
    })
        .then(response => {
            console.log("resreeeee", response)

        })
  }
}
```

Comment: You are callling `return Promise` before `this.setState`, with `return` statement you closed the function execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two parts are problematic:

- calling and returning `Promise.all` inside the loop

  ```
  for (var i = 0; i < response.Airports.length; i++) {
     result.push(anyDestinationData(response.Airports[i].code, input.departuredate, input.returndate, input.maxfare))

     return Promise.all(result).then(function (results) {
  ```

  Once a `return` statement is encountered, the execution of the function will not continue. Putting it in a loop without a condition will always result with the function stopping execution in the first iteration (assuming the loop condition is satisfied).

  In your case, the `result` array will always contain one element before being passed to `Promise.all`, and the resultant promise returned.
- referring to the wrong `this` inside function - its value is determined at *function call*, not *function definition* (not the case with arrow functions).

  ```
  return Promise.all(result).then(function(results) {
     //...
     this.setState({
  ```

This should work:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  handleInput() {
    multipleAirports(this.state.input.origin.value).then( response => {
      // Populate the array.
      const result = response.Airports.map(airport => anyDestinationData(airport.code, input.departuredate, input.returndate, input.maxfare));

      // Pass it to `Promise.all` and return it.
      return Promise.all(result).then( results => {
        const data = results.map(item => ({ [item.data.OriginLocation]: item.data.FareInfo }))
        this.setState({
          flightData: data
        })
      })   
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log("resreeeee", response)
    })
  }
}
```

Note I replaced the `for` loops with `.map` calls, and `var`s with `const`/`let`s, as you're already using ES7 features.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Now it works. Just for understanding, could you please explain what happens when I return the promise insight the loop /how it affects 'data'? Regarding the this, I thought its just referring to the component (App)? Could you also explain that in this case? (Im not too experienced with react,promises etc). Thank you :)

Comment: Take a look at the edit, I'd say the main issue here is unrelated to promises or react, and about control flow in general.

Answer (score 1):

As written `this.setState()` doesn't do what you want for the a number of reasons :

- returning from inside the `for` loop terminates not only the loop but also the entire `.then()` callback.
- `Promise.all(result).then(...)` needs to be outside the loop.
- `this.setState` needs to be inside the `Promise.all(result).then(...)` callback.

The goal here is much simpler to achieve than might first appear.

The basic pattern you seek is :

```
myFn() {
    // return a Promise to myFn's caller - shouldn't hurt even if not necessary
    return doSomethingAsync()
    .then(response => {
        // map `responses` to an array of promises
        var promises = response.map(item => doSomethingElseAsync(item));
        // aggregate `promises` and return a promise that delivers an array of results from doSomethingElseAsync().
        return Promise.all(promises);
    })
    .then(data => {
        // do something with <Array> `data`
        this.setState({
            flightData: data.map(/* some transform of `data` */)
        });
        return data; // optional - deliver `data` (via the returned Promise) to myFn's caller.
    });
}
```

In full :

```
class App extends React.Component {
    handleInput() {
        var input = this.state.input;
        return multipleAirports(input.origin.value)
        .then(response => {
            // map `response.Airports` to an array of promises (originally named `result`)
            var promises = response.Airports.map(airport => anyDestinationData(
                airport.code,
                input.departuredate,
                input.returndate,
                input.maxfare
            ));
            // aggregate `promises` and return a Promise that delivers an array of flights (presumably).
            return Promise.all(promises);
        })
        .then(flights => {
            // map `flights` to array of specialised objects
            var data = flights.map(item => {
                return { [item.data.OriginLocation]: item.data.FareInfo };
            });
            this.setState({
                flightData: data
            });
            return data; // optional - make `data` (or `flights`?) available to handleInput's caller.
        });
    }
}
```

Notes :

- Promises deliver data and although it is sometimes convenient, it is seldom necessary to "pass" data via outer members. The question's `var test` is unnecessary.
- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) makes for very concise code (twice).

Answer (score 0):

Why is it that you have returned the Promise.all inside the for loop? Populate the `result` with what you need and then use it for Promise.all(). When each and every one of those promises is resolved you will receive the output in the then(). I'm assuming `anyDestinationData` is a promise here. Also add consoles everywhere to check since when it is becoming `undefined`.

Comment: my logs show the 'test' is already just an empty array right after when I declare test= data and again, I am not sure what to do here

Comment: by everywhere I meant right from `results`. It is possible some promise is failing and hence Promise.all is not being resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    handleInput = () => {
        const {
          input,
          input: { origin: {
            value
          }}
        } = this.state;

        multipleAirports(value)
          .then((response) => {
              const results = response.Airports.map(airport => anyDestinationData(airport.code, input.departuredate, input.returndate, input.maxfare));

              return Promise.all(results)
                .then((result) => {
                  results.map((item) => {
                    const data = result.map(item => ({
                      [item.data.OriginLocation]: item.data.FareInfo
                    }))
                    this.setState({
                      flightData: data
                    })
                  })
                })
                .then(response => {
                  console.log("resreeeee", response)
                })
            }
          }
```

I modified your code slightly, kindly see if that works. I took the `Promise.all` out of the loop and then `setState` inside the promise.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, it still shows the error ' Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined '

Comment: See change I made to the `handleInput` method, I used arrow function to define it, this way `setState` will be defined.

Comment: Made some additional changes, kindly try it again.